# data order misrepresented in firefox

Tags: python, firefox

```
    my_list=[{'36': 478.0, '36.5': 440.0,'37.5': 490.0, '38': 478.0,'38.5': 425.0,'39': 388.0,
  '40': 320.0,
  '40.5': 292.0,
  '41': 289.0,
  '42': 288.0,
  '42.5': 290.0,
  '43': 289.0,
  '44': 275.0,
  '44.5': 272.0,
  '45': 270.0,
  '45.5': 281.0,
  '46': 275.0,
  '47': 285.0,
  '47.5': 265.0,
  '48': 310.0,
  '48.5': 304.0,
  '49': '',
  '49.5': 295.0,
  '50.5': 269.0,
  '51.5': 337.0,
  '52.5': 285.0},
 {'40': 271.0,
  '40.5': 254.0,
  '41': 234.0,
  '42': 239.0,
  '42.5': 230.0,
  '43': 230.0,
  '44': 225.0,
  '44.5': 235.0,
  '45': 235.0,
  '45.5': 246.0,
  '46': 235.0,
  '47': 244.0,
  '47.5': 238.0,
  '48': '',
  '48.5': 240.0,
  '49': '',
  '49.5': 245.0,
  '50.5': 220.0,
  '51.5': 235.0,
  '52.5': 245.0},
 {'37.5': 225.0,
  '38': 223.0,
  '38.5': 230.0,
  '39': 226.0,
  '40': 222.0,
  '40.5': 229.0,
  '41': 230.0,
  '42': 223.0,
  '42.5': 229.0,
  '43': 230.0,
  '44': 235.0,
  '44.5': 238.0,
  '45': 234.0,
  '45.5': 240.0,
  '46': 231.0,
  '47': 238.0,
  '47.5': 240.0,
  '48': 241.0,
  '48.5': 245.0,
  '49': 254.0,
  '49.5': 690.0,
  '50': 240.0,
  '50.5': 10938327.0,
  '51': 235.0}]


import json
with open('Output.json', 'w') as fout:
    json.dump(my_list , fout)
```

when I opened the file in Firefox it rearranged the items in a different order than I wanted (specified in python)
I tried using

```
[dict(sorted(d.items())) for d in my_list]
```

then writing to file but it didn't solve, when I open in a text editor it is correct, is this a firefox option? is there a way to view it in Firefox "normally" in my order?

Note: I use python3.7.5

Comment: Python dictionaries aren't ordered.

Comment: @Barmar yes they are

Comment: i'd guess that whatever firefox extension you are using to view the JSON probably sorts the keys or something.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I am using default Firefox (without extensions that comes pre-installed on Ubuntu)

Comment: @User1984 I don't have firefox installed, but does it comes with some JSON viewer? I bet it does.

Comment: @Barmar I use python3.7.5

Comment: @RoadRunner in question he clearly says when opened in text editor output is "correct"

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the problem is that the default Firefox JSON viewer "pretty prints" the JSON, at least in version 74 which I am running.

It seems that the firefox json pretty printer treats string versions of integers and decimals differently and puts the decimal values after the integers, thus appearing out of order.

The JSON viewer in Firefox 74 gives a tab to allow access to the data in it's raw form which shows the correctly ordered data.

Otherwise, if you wanted to have it be viewed in the correct order by default, you could change the JSON keys that you are writing to always include a decimal place. Like so:

```py
my_list = [{'36.0': 478.0, '36.5': 440.0,'37.5': 490.0, '38.0': 478.0}]
```